# CPU is 99% when write a threading application

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, cpu-usage

im create a windows application C# like a download Manager 
when run this application i found the CPU is 99% and i write a threading
application how i can start to solve this Problem

thank you

Comment: You're going to need to tell us what you are doing in order to get some help. The experts on Stack Overflow are fabulous but they do not read minds.

Comment: @David - I believe Nick Craver does read minds, but he doesn't seem to be around yet.

Comment: Start by looking at the task manager. Is it really your application that is eating the CPU? If yes then try to add some logging statement in your application to see which part is stuck in a loop. Try and isolate that part of application which has the problem and then you can solve it.

Comment: So you wrote code to start a bunch of threads and now you find out they are running.  This is not a problem, it's working.  Lower their priority if you don't like them slowing down the user interface.

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem?  The *opposite* would be a problem! if the CPU utilization is below 100% in a multithreaded application then *you have threads that are not being scheduled to do work*. The whole *point* of multithreading is to keep the CPU going so that work gets done as fast as possible in the background. Can you explain why you think using your CPU is a problem?

Comment: @eric it's presumably a problem because a download manager would likely consume little or no cpu

Comment: @David: That makes sense, though of course if the problem is that *unnecessary* work is being done then that is a problem irrespective of the threading logic. A single-threaded program that does unnecessary work is also doing unnecessary work. The solution: find the unnecessary work and stop doing it.

Comment: @Eric Indeed. We need Nick Craver to arrive with his reputed mind reading skills!! Ah, I've just seen that Mr. Skeet has used his mind reading powers and got the acceptance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for any tight loops you've got in your code - it's almost certainly due to one of those. Something like this:

```
while (!finished)
{
    progressBar.Value = DownloadProgress;
}
```

Without seeing your code though, it's hard to guess any more accurately than that.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start by profiling your application to identify hot spots and then rework through the code to eliminate the same. Profile your application - number of active threads - CPU consumed by the different threads, profile functions to catch any CPU heavy function.

Comment: i used the progress bar , my be is a progress bar is problem

Comment: I often was wrong when assuming a performance bottle neck; that's why it is so important to use a profiler, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, profiling is a good idea. Use e.g. Red Gate [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) which is free to test for 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite place for threading, I don't think you can find a simpler article on threading strategies.

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 0):

I would try with Jons answer and then implement Muek answer.

You are having tight loops somewhere in your code.  Despite low priority (if you used it) - if you have a loop that doesn't release the control back to the kernel thread scheduler it will consume all of the CPU until control is TAKEN from it.  For example you can have:

```
while (!_shouldStop)
{
    DoProcessing();
}
```

This really *IS* bad, because it will certainly use all of your CPU.

To solve this, easiest way is to use either Sleep(100) or Sleep(0) inside your loop, something like:

```
while (!_shouldStop)
{
    DoProcessing();
    Thread.Sleep(0);
}
```

There are also better (and somehow more complicated ways) to do this - events for example - but for start, your app will behave much better with that here.